# View.draw(canvas) leaves gray border around circular png set in ImageView

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, transparent

I have an `ImageView` whose `src` is being set to a transparent square png with rounded corners.

I am calling `View.draw(canvas)` on the `ImageView` to take a screenshot. It leaves a gray border around the rounded corners like the [image in the link](http://free.iiifhosting.com/iiif/3531bd0db318e3158a1dba4bb6407b719b1b2684dd3d16aee215e83cfa4d1fdc/)

What can I do to remove the gray border?

Here is what I have tried..

```
        Bitmap viewBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBmp);
        if(isToMakeTransperant) canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        myView.draw(canvas);
```

I have already tried setting `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` in `drawColor()` method. It didn't work.

edit : yes, the `isToMakeTransperant boolean` is always true. I have hard coded it to `true` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

you can create transition bitmap

```
Bipmap bimap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmaoFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.color.transtion), 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: just tried it. didn't work. image is same as in attached link.

Comment: it made the entire image transparent. nothing was shown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310489/how-do-i-remove-the-light-grey-border-around-my-canvas-widget