# Border around button widget when using an image are there any fixes in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I am using a button widget and trying to put an image onto the button but the border of the button still shows up. This is similar to another complaint i had but the same fix doesnt work.

Comment: You can specify the size of the button as the size of the image.

Comment: have you tried setting the borderwidth option to zero?

Comment: @acw1668 There will always be a small border around the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bryan Oakley stated in his comment, *have you tried setting the borderwidth option to zero?*

That is precisely what you need to do.

When creating the button:

```
b = Button(master, ..., borderwidth = 0)
b.pack()
```

Hope this helps!

Note: Look at BryanOakley's answer on [highligththickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310489/how-do-i-remove-the-light-grey-border-around-my-canvas-widget). This can also be useful at times.

Comment: _” Note: For a Canvas or Frame widget, use highlightthickness = 0 instead.”_ is not true. `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` are not the same, and `Button`, `Canvas`, and `Frame` all support both.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know, I just mentioned that highlightthickness exists for those widgets. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: You shouldn’t use it _instead_. They serve different purposes.

Comment: I have noticed when I use it for a Canvas widget that it removes a white border around a Canvas. In other words, it expands to fill a widget perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it removes the highlight ring. That’s different from the border.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have stated that in my answer.

Comment: Not really,  your terminology is a bit confusing You say you can use `highlightthickness=0` instead of `borderwidth=0`, but that isn't guaranteed to remove the border. A canvas can have both a highlight ring _and_ a border. Using `highlightthickness` instead of `borderwidth` won't remove the border.