# Unwanted border appearing when scrollable canvas added

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, border, frame

I've coded a scrollbar into my app which works like a treat. The only issue is that there is an annoying black frame which apperas around the edges (see below):

[image]

The frame I'm talking about is to the right of the scroll bar and above the "Ply builder" title.

My scrollbar code is:

```
"""Scroll bar"""
        canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0)
        scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
        vsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, width=450, height=725)

        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

        scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Not sure if the border is controlled by the `Canvas`, `Frame` or window element.  I also don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Add `highlightthickness=0` in `Canvas(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the light grey border around my Canvas widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310489/how-do-i-remove-the-light-grey-border-around-my-canvas-widget)

Answer (score 1):

As @acw1668 said in the comments,

> Add `highlightthickness` in `Canvas(...)`

That is the most reasonable solution, and it can be achieved like so:

```py
canvas = Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness = 0)
scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
vsb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, width=450, height=725)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Read more about the [`highlightthickness`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) parameter.

> The width of the highlight border. The default is system specific (usually one or two pixels). (highlightThickness/HighlightThickness)

Hope this helps!